# ajax update progress bar control not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have been working on a project but i got stuck on a problem as i have to use progress bar while inserting data in table which takes bit of time..but my code is not working ..please check out the code as given below

```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <Triggers> 
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsubmit" EventName="Click"/>
   </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" 
     OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
   </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" 
   AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ProgressTemplate> 
  <img src="animated.gif" alt=""/> </ProgressTemplate> 
  </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

and i have used java script code as

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    var postBackElement;
    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
        if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack())
            args.set_cancel(true);
        postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();

        if (postBackElement.id == 'btnsubmit')
            $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        if (postBackElement.id == 'btnsubmit')
            $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

please provide me  a solution for it i will be really thankful to you...